How to customise subgrid form to inherit data from parent table?
I have a custom table called 'Object Tracking' and I want to add it as a subgrid under the 'Account' table, where Account is the parent, and Object Tracking is the child.
Here’s the requirement:

When someone creates a new Account entry, they should see an option in the subgrid to add a new Object Tracking entry.
This new Object Tracking entry should automatically link to the Account as the parent.
Adding a new Object Tracking entry should only be possible once the Account entry has been saved.
The Account page should only display Object Tracking entries that are associated with that specific Account.

Below is an example with screen shots -
Parent - Opportunity table
Child - Quote table
Quote subgrid is hidden as Oppotunity is not saved yet.

We get option to create new Quote, once Opportunity is saved.

The new Quote form automatically inherits the Parent Opportunity(DemoOpp4).


this is the default functionality that can be achieved using some simple steps.

when you create a lookup field of account on object tracking.
then add a sub-grid on account (make sure to selected related records and entity only) and it will only show when the record is saved.
'+' button to add an object is available by default
when you add, the account will be populated by default.

you do not have to do any out of the box thing to achieve this functionality
